# Hybris- create one site with more base store

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

i need to assign to a single cmssite more stores with it's own sap Base Store Configuration.

at the moment, i've created two base store, and assigned those to a single website.

problem is that baseStoreService.getCurrentBaseStore(); is getting always the first entry, and i can't find out the logic to select the right base store.

How can i customize this functionality? how hybris select the base store?

Best regards
Marco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BaseStoreService` has a list of `BaseStoreSelectorStrategy` beans injected & those perform the mechanics of selecting a store.  The only standard implementation for the strategy is `DefaultBaseStoreSelectorStrategy` which just choses the first store for the current site.  I imagine you will need to customise this with your own strategy implementation(s).